# mysql stop increasing with quantity

Tags: mysql, foreach

I've been sorting this problem in my head but not getting any success.
See the view query in mySQL here:

```
SELECT
    concat(
        Windows_last_options.company,
        ' | ',
        Windows_last_options.material,
        ' | ',
        '$',
        Windows_last_options.newcost
    ) AS options,
    round(
        (
            (
                Windows_last_options.newcost * 0.50
            ) + 100
        ),
        2
    ) AS depositcost,
    (
        trim(
            substring_index(
                Windows_last_submissions_ONE.requested,
                'Quantity:' ,- (1)
            )
        ) + 0
    ) AS quantity
FROM
    (
        Windows_last_submissions_ONE
        JOIN Windows_last_options
    )
```

Currently, it will increase 'newcost' by $100.00 for every quantity the user chooses (ie, it will go up $500 if the user chose quantity:5).

What I want is for it to only go up by $100 one time (this is the initial deposit regardless of quantity)- unfortunately it currently goes up by 100 for every quantity over 0.

I was thinking a foreach but I don't think mysql allows that (I do not know how to store procedural statements).

Comment: . . Please format your query. Hint:  four spaces at the beginning of each line put it in code format.

Comment: Sorry about that I thought I did.  I usually highlight it and use the "{}".

Comment: ... So where is the formatted code. - I.e. not requiring the scroll bar

Comment: Don't quite understand.  Spacing it four spaces (formatting it) puts it in code format but a long scrollable div...If I remove spaces no more scroll area but no more fomattable code.

Comment: Have you heard to concept of multiple lines for the code

Comment: Is the JOIN syntax correct? Missing the condition